# Tooltips in Eclipse RCP window toolbar menus

Tags: eclipse, menu, toolbar, rcp, tooltip

I created a window with a toolbar with menus. Now I want menu items to have tooltips, and I did not succeed.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

What I've already tryed:

1. Set the 'tooltip' for menu contribution in plugin.xml
2. Set the 'description' for the command
3. Setup tooltip text in the actions in submenus that I create programmatically using ManuManager and Action.

Regards,
Vladimir

Answer (score 1):

According to the description of the [popupMenus](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_popupMenus.html) extension point tooltips are only shown when the action is part of a toolbar. There exists an [Eclipse Bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=62575) considering this problem.